# How to make ng-select remove-and-read-only

Tags: css, angular, angular-ngselect

In my Angular application, I have an instance of the [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) widget:

[image]

If you click on it, by default you can search for items and add more of them to the current selection:

[image]

I would like to change this default behaviour, in particular:

- it shouldn **not** be possible to add new elements
- clicking on it should **not** open the search bar or the items list
- it should **not** show the arrow down icon (displayed by default on the right)
- it should **not** show the X icon to remove all selection at once (displayed by default on the right)

So this is how I would like it to be:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to achieve this, we first need to create 3 css classes.

One to disable the arrow-down icon:

```
.ng-select.disable-arrow .ng-arrow-wrapper .ng-arrow {
  display: none;
}
```

One to disable the search/list dropdown:

```
.ng-select.disable-dropdown ng-dropdown-panel {
  display: none;
}
```

One to disable the clear-all X icon:

```
.ng-select.disable-clear-all .ng-clear-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

Then we add the `ng-select` element using the 3 css classes that we created, plus a few options:

```
<ng-select
  class="disable-arrow disable-dropdown disable-clear-all"
  [searchable]="false"
  [clearable]="true"
  [multiple]="true"
>
</ng-select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one minor thing:
When this is selected now the corner radii change from rounded so I added this code to prevent that
```.ng-select.ng-select-opened.ng-select-bottom > .ng-select-container {
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px !important;
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px !important;
                }```

Answer (score 3):

To disable the clear-all X icon add `[clearable]="false"` attribute to your `ng-select` tab ex.:

```
<ng-select class="disable-clear-all" [clearable]="false" [searchable]="false">
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking to do that simply in 2023 you just have to add readonly to true to the ng-select element:

```
[readonly]="true"
```

cf documentation : https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select

Answer (score 0):

To hide the clear and arrow icons:

```css
.ng-clear-wrapper {display: none;}

.ng-arrow-wrapper {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is only what u need if u need it programmatically.

```
<ng-select
    [items]="people3"
    bindLabel="name"
    [disabled]="true"
    [multiple]="true"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedPeople3">
</ng-select>
```